# Problems Converting Floats

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, math, game-development, conversion-specifier

I'm new to Unity and C#. I'm making a clicker game where you write books for money. In order to calculate how much each book should be worth in dollars I have a script called "Money Calculations" where I calculate how much money a book with certain creativity and number of pages should be worth, then I send the number of pages and the book's creativity as variables to my other script "money display". After running simple mathematical functions in Money Calculations I come out with a whole number, which is what I want.

This is the script which generates the dollar amount and calls a method to another script below to take the number and display it. This bit is the "Money Calculations":

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class Money Calculations : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static int cashAmount;
    public static float pages;
    public static float creativity;
        
    public void displayMoney()
    {
        //money formula
        pages = Mathf.RoundToInt(CriticsP.numOfPages);
        creativity = Mathf.RoundToInt(CriticsC.creativity);
        // -Critics C and P are other scripts
        // -pages and creativity start as float values
       
        cashAmount = (int)(pages / 3) + (int)(creativity * 4);

        //cashAmount is dollar value to be sent to Money Display
        MoneyDisplay.add();
    }
}
```

And here I have the display script, "Money Display"

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
 
public class MoneyDisplay : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static int cashOnHand;
    public Text cashMoney;

    void Update()
    {
        cashMoney.text = cashOnHand.ToString();
    }
    
    public static void add()
    {
        // **
        cashOnHand += (int)MoneyCalculations.cashAmount;
    }
}
```

The problem I'm running into is where I have the asterisks. The original numbers for pages and creativity were floats, I was having trouble doing calculations on them as ints. So I figured I could convert them to ints before I displayed the final number, cashOnHand, which is an int. Even though I've said several times for C# to convert pages and creativity to ints, I think I must be doing it wrong. When I say `cashOnHand = (int)MoneyCalculations.cashAmount` the number the game displays is a whole number, the same number exactly as the previous script generates. But for some reason when I tell the computer `cashOnHand * += * (int)MoneyCalculations.cashAmount` (asterisks for emphasis) it prints a wild number, like 7880 instead of 325 like I need. I suspect it's reverting to it's base float value and changing from the integer I'm looking for, I don't know why the number returns to a float when I specifically perform a += function, and I'm out of ideas to fix it.

I've tried doing several conversions from float to int in order to get my number, but I was unable to maintain page number and creativity as ints throughout the development process and had to use floats for lack of expertise. I'm afraid it could be too late now, as the floats are ingrained in the code in several places and I'm worried a simple conversion may not be enough, but I don't know. If my case is hopeless, could you refer me to a resource on performing math functions on integers without having to have them as floats?

Comment: Where is `displayMoney` called? Like every frame from `Update`? Using += will make that number really big really fast if you are adding to it every frame. You might consider passing parameters between functions where you can instead of referencing another script.

Comment: Hello yes I made sure to call displayMoney from inside a method from money Calculations, and not from within an update method. Originally I had the += located in money calculations, and money calculations would do the calculations and also display the number as text, but I moved those features to MoneyDisplay because it was still outputting large numbers and I wanted to tackle the problem from a different perspective. The numbers that are generated I believe are the old float values of the converted ints, as a dollar amount of 79 for example would output something like 79000

Comment: Simple answer is don't use the asterisks - they are a multiplier in programming languages.

Comment: You've not given us a [mcve]. You've not given us your input numbers so we cannot know if your code or your inputs are wrong. You've also not even told us your actual outputs - you've only told us what they're "like". Can you please fix your question?

Comment: Also, you're making your life harder than it needs to be by creating `static` fields and methods.